# Convergence in distribution and probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Suppose ${X_{n}}$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables with cumulative distribution function given by $F_{X_{n}}(x) = 1 - 1/(1+nx)$ for $x\geq 0$.
Examine if $\{X_{n}\}$ converges in distribution, probability and mean square to $X=0$.

I have problems in solving this question, how can I solve the probability and mean square convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x>0$, $\{F_{X_n}(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to zero, hence we have convergence in distribution.

Since the pdf of $X_n$ is given by $f_{X_n}(x)=\frac{n}{(1+nx)^2}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{x\geq 0}$, we have:
$$\mathbb{P}[|X_n|\geq\varepsilon]=\int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{(1+nx)^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{1+n\varepsilon}$$
whose limit when $n\to+\infty$ is zero, hence we have convergence in probability.

However, $X_n$ does not have a second moment, since
$$\mathbb{E}[|X_n|^2] = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{nx^2}{(1+nx)^2}\,dx = +\infty,$$
so we do not have convergence in $L^2$ (neither in $L^1$).

Comment: i am wordless!!, how can i miss this?...thank you very much, :)